# badblocks command in linux got stuck after checking certain blocks. Does that mean there is any issue with the sd card?

Tags: badblocks

badblocks command in linux got stuck after checking certain blocks. Does that mean there is any issue with the sd card ?
sys]$badblocks -v /dev/mmcblk0p1
Checking blocks 0 to 1231646
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): 0
1
2
3
4
:
:
189315
189316 <- stuck here

Please provide your suggestion.